torchtext and fasttext vectorization
I found example with use ready vectors for Glove (for FastText the same example) :
`# set up fields
TEXT = data.Field(lower=True, include_lengths=True, batch_first=True)
LABEL = data.Field(sequential=False)

# make splits for data
train, test = datasets.IMDB.splits(TEXT, LABEL)

# build the vocabulary
TEXT.build_vocab(train, vectors=GloVe(name='6B', dim=300))
LABEL.build_vocab(train)

# make iterator for splits
train_iter, test_iter = data.BucketIterator.splits(
    (train, test), batch_size=3, device=0)`

I try to use my pretrained model FastText and vectors, but I get errrors:

`vectors = get_vectors(model_ft, result_df['text_processed'])

max_size = 30000
TEXT.build_vocab(train_data, vectors=vectors, max_size=max_size)
LABEL.build_vocab(train_data)`

But how can I create and use FastText for vectorization my text use my model FastText in pytorchtext?
I didn't find explained in doc(
